# using android with json to get data from web and intent to display the details on the second activity did not work

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-listview

i am creating android app that take data from website using JSONParser and display this data in a listview (at this case the app work perfectly).
then i add another activity that will display the details  in the second activity when the user select and click an item from the list.

the problem is that the data appear in the list and the user select the data but the system show in the second activity the values of the **JSON TAG nodes** and not the values of the selected data .

means  the data is like :

From the logCat:

```
03-14 08:40:29.845: E/position of the Item in the list(1309): you select the item number {"adminName2":"Politischer Bezirk Reutte","adminCode3":"70820","postalcode":"6600","adminCode2":"708","adminName3":"Lechaschau","adminCode1":"07","countryCode":"AT","placeName":"Lechaschau","lng":10.7,"lat":47.4833333,"adminName1":"Tirol"}
```

and what the system show in the application is these values :

```
private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName";==the first value
private static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng";the second value
private static final String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";the third value
private static final String POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode";the fourth value
private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";
```

can anyone help  to fix this error?

## added chunk

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        try {
            PostalCodes.get(position);
            String  PLACENAME = postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG).toString();
            String  LATITUDE = postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  LONGITUDE = postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  POSTALCODE = postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG).toString();



            Log.e("position of the Item in the list", "you select the item number " + PostalCodes.getString(position));
            Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Row_Item.class);
            in.putExtra("placename", PLACENAME);
            in.putExtra("lat",  LATITUDE);
            in.putExtra("lng", LONGITUDE);
            in.putExtra("postaCode", POSTALCODE);
            startActivity(in);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error in the onListItemClick",
                    "LOOK AT THE onListItemClick method");
        }

    }
```

this is the code

## JSONActivityHttpClient

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class JsonActivityHttpClient extends ListActivity {

    // ***from JsonHandlerClass****//
    JSONArray PostalCodes;
    List<String> result;

    JSONObject jsonObject;

    private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng";
    private static final String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";
    // private static final String ADMIN_NAME_TAG = "adminCode3";
    private static final String POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode";
    private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";

    // ***from JsonHandlerClass****//

    JSONParserHandler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new HTTPGetTask().execute();

    }

    private class HTTPGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        private static final String USER_NAME = "devleb";

        private static final String URL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username="
                + USER_NAME;

        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

            JSONParserHandler responseHandler = new JSONParserHandler();
            try {

                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (null != mClient) {

                mClient.close();

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        JsonActivityHttpClient.this, R.layout.list_item, result));

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.json_activity_http_client, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        try {
            PostalCodes.get(position);
            Log.e("position of the Item in the list", "you select the item number " + PostalCodes.getString(position));
            Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Row_Item.class);
            in.putExtra("placename", PLACE_NAME_TAG);
            in.putExtra("lat", LATITUDE_TAG);
            in.putExtra("lng", LONGITUDE_TAG);
            in.putExtra("postaCode", POSTAL_CODE_TAG);
            startActivity(in);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error in the onListItemClick",
                    "LOOK AT THE onListItemClick method");
        }

    }

    // *************JSONParserHandler*******************************//

    private class JSONParserHandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>> {
        /*
         * private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName"; private
         * static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng"; private static final
         * String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat"; private static final String
         * ADMIN_NAME_TAG = "adminCode3"; private static final String
         * POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode"; private static final String
         * POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";
         */
        @Override
        public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            result = new ArrayList<String>();
            String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler()
                    .handleResponse(response);

            try {

                jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(JSONResponse)
                        .nextValue();

                PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(POSTALCODE);

                for (int i = 0; i < PostalCodes.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject postalCode = (JSONObject) PostalCodes.get(i);

                    result.add(postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG) + "\n"
                            + POSTAL_CODE_TAG + ":"
                            + postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG) + LATITUDE_TAG
                            + ":" + postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG) + "\n"
                            + LONGITUDE_TAG + ":"
                            + postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG));
                }
            } catch (JSONException E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    // *************JSONParserHandler*******************************//

}
```

## Row_Item

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Row_Item extends Activity {

    TextView Place_Name, txtlat,txtlng, txtPostalCode;

    String value1,value2,value3,value4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_row__item);

        Place_Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLAT);
        txtlng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLNG);
        txtPostalCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPSTC);


        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        value1 = b.getString("placename");
        value2 = b.getString("lat");
        value3 = b.getString("lng");
        value4 = b.getString("postaCode");

        Place_Name.setText(value1);
        txtlat.setText(value2);
        txtlng.setText(value3);
        txtPostalCode.setText(value4);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.row__item, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is the URL of the JSON API  **http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=devleb"**

Comment: You are populating the intent with the keys, not the values. For instance, in.putExtra("placename", PLACE_NAME_TAG); results in "placename" as the key and "placename" as the value (because PLACE_NAME_TAG is just a variable). Try getting the String at the clicked position instead.

Comment: This will read the String at the current clicked position. String item = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position); You can then put that in your intent.  in.putExtra("placename", item);

Comment: @ burntsugar i will add to my question the chunk of code that i add it   take a look

Comment: In handleResponse you are formatting all of the values with colons as a single String which is getting returned to the ListView. Is the ListView behaving the way you want it to?

Comment: no actually the result after clicking is always the final row in the listview